# Attempt to read property "nodeValue" on null

Tags: php, web-scraping, xpath, nodevalue

```
$playerNames = $xpath->query('//table/tbody/tr/td[@class="hauptlink"]/a');

...

$playerName = $playerNames[$i]->nodeValue;
```

I'm trying to do web scraping with XPath using PHP from transfermarkt.com, but  the path that contains the name of the players returns null, even if the path is correct

How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: Just one suggestion. Xpath query is pretty fussy about valid XML/HTML. Maybe try validating your input with `DOMDocument validate()`

Comment: Did you check if the html is populated via js?